# ActionController::UnknownFormat in StocksController#search

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to use Ajax for the first time on a tutorial.  The goal is to type in a stock identifier, press a button, and it brings up info about that stock on the same page without reloading it.  I'm getting no error messages, and when I go into the console it shows under the network response the partial's HTML code with the correct stock information, it's just not pushing it onto the screen.  When I click the network response it gives me an unknownformat error.

Relevant code:

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController 
   def search
      if params[:stock].present?
         @stock = Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])
         if @stock 
            respond_to do |format|
               format.js {render partial: 'users/result'}
            end
         else
            puts "incorrect symbol"
            flash[:danger] = "You have entered an incorrect symbol."
            redirect_to my_portfolio_path
      end

      else
         puts "nothing"
         flash[:danger] = "You need to type something, what did you expect to happen?"
         redirect_to my_portfolio_path
      end
   end
end
```

Results partial:

```
<%if @stock%>
    <div class = "well results-block">
        <strong>Symbol:</strong><%= @stock.ticker%>
        <strong>Name:</strong><%= @stock.name%>
        <strong>Last Price:</strong><%= @stock.last_price%>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

Results JS erb

```
$('#result').html("<%=j (render 'users/result.html')%>")
```

The webpage itself

```
<h1>My portfolio</h1>
<h3>Search for stocks</h3>
<div id = "stock-lookup">
    <%=form_tag search_stocks_path,remote: true,method: :get, id: "stock-lookup-form" do%>
        <row>
            <div class = "form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
                <div class = "col-md-10">
                    <%=text_field_tag :stock, params[:stock], placeholder: "Stock ticker symbol", autofocus: true, class: "form-control search-box input-lg" %>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-md-2">
                    <%=button_tag(type: :submit, class:"btn btn-lg btn-success") do%>
                        <i class = "fa fa-search"></i> Look Up A Stock
                    <%end%>
                </div>    
            </div>

        </row>


    <%end%>
</div>

<div id= "results">
    <%=render 'result'%>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you target `#results` instead of `#result` like

```
$('#results').html("<%=j (render 'users/result.html')%>")
```

Answer (score 1):

If a `@stock` was found you are using the correct format JS. But when not you are redirecting to `my_portfolio_path` and I assume that this action is returning format HTML. Why redirecting to my_portfolio_path? I think for your AJAX route this is not needed.

I think this example is a better approach for your `SearchController`:

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController 
  def search
    @stock = Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])
    flash[:danger] = "No stock found." if @stock.nil?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render partial: 'users/result'}
    end 
  end
end
```

This is your JS template:

```
<% if @stock %>
  $('#results').html("<%=j (render 'users/result.html')%>");
<% else %>
  console.log("No stock found! It's up to you what to do in frontend.")
  // showing some flash!
  // however_you_render_flash_in_you_app();
<% end %>
```

Comment: I recommend you to return a list with limit/pagination for search results and render all. To only return 1 search result could be frustrating for the user.

Comment: While this is good, when I'm not finding things it's working properly...The page isn't working properly when it DOES find stock...any ideas?

Comment: Also, as for the pagination, because they're entering the EXACT ticker of the stock, there should always only be one result...Unless I don't understand how stock works. Also it is for a tutorial, so the main reason I'm doing this is to get ajax to work.  This won't leave development stage.